# Passing a password into a script

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am currently using the below PowerShell script to update an autologon value in the registry, it also checks that if the value isn't there that it is created.

Rather than opening up the script, changing the defaultpassword value in there and then running the script I'd like to be able to run the script in PowerShell and for it to prompt for the user to enter the value that is going to update.

I am new to parameters within PowerShell and can't say I'm 100% sure that is the solution.

Can anyone help? it's the 'passwordvalue' I'm looking to have inputed from a prompt and to be subsequently replaced in the script before the script runs.  Let me know if I'm not being clear!

```
$RegKey = “HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS NT\CURRENTVERSION\WINLOGON”
if (-Not(Test-Path “$RegKey”)) {
New-Item -Path “$($RegKey.TrimEnd($RegKey.Split(‘\’)[-1]))” -Name “$($RegKey.Split(‘\’)[-1])” -Force | Out-Null
 }
 Set-ItemProperty -Path “$RegKey” -Name “DefaultPassword” -Type String -Value “passwordvalue”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `Read-Host` cmdlet:

```
# ....
Set-ItemProperty -Path "$RegKey" -Name "DefaultPassword" -Type String -Value (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the password')
```

Comment: Perfect! So simple when you know how!  Thanks for responding so quickly.